# Get value from multiple Switch in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have multiple switch (around 40 to 70) in a component depending on the number of rows fetched from database. I am rendering each switch with every row in a flatlist (every item is assigned with a ID). In the end, I want to submit all the values and store them in database along with id and and it;s respective switch status (true / false).

I want to do it like a form in HTML where we get all the values of form after submitting the form.

This is the component where flatlist is rendered. I have removed unnecessary code because I am able to display the flat list without any error and warning.

```
const [stData, setStData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=> {
   // Here I am fetching data from server using axios
   // setStData(fetchedData);
})
<View>

  <FlatList
      data={stData}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.registration_id}
      renderItem={(stData) => (
          <ListItem
             name={stData.item.name}
             registrationNo={stData.item.registration_id}
             data={stData}
             isPresent={stData.item.isPresent}
             setData={setStData}
          />
       )}
   />
```

This is ListItem component

```
<View>
      <View>
        <Text>{props.name}</Text>
        <Text>{props.id}</Text>
      </View>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{ true: "red" }}
        thumbColor={"white"}
        onValueChange={() =>
          props.setData(
            props.data.map((item) =>
              item.registration_id === props.registrationNo
                ? { ...item, isPresent: !props.isPresent }
                : item
            )
          )
        }
        value={props.isPresent}
      />
</View>
```

**Update**
Now whenever I am trying to toggle the switch button, **TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...props.data.map...')** is occured.

Answer (score 0):

While creating `const [isPresent, setIsPresent] = useState(false);` at child component, you make it a bit rough unnesserally for adding it afterwards to `stData`, consider store it there from the begging

---

```
// dummy data with { isPresent } at main obj
const [data, setData] = useState(stData.map(obj => {...obj, isPresent: false})


<View>
   <FlatList
       data={data}
       keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
       renderItem={({item, id, isPresent}) => (
     <ListItem
         name={item}
         id={id}
         data={data}
         setData={setData}
         isPresent={isPresent}
     />
    )}
   />
</View>





// child component
<View>
   <View>
      <Text>{props.name}</Text>
      <Text>{props.id}</Text>
   </View>
   <Switch
    trackColor={{ true: "red" }}
    thumbColor={"white"}
    onValueChange={() => props.setData(props.data.map(item => item.id == props.id ? { ...item, isPresent: !props.isPresent } : item)}
    value={props.isPresent}
  />
</View>
```

---

*EDIT*

when you call `renderItem={(stData) =>`,
`stData` in scope of this `renderItem` isn't `stData` from state anymore, including at `data={stData}`

change it to

---

```
  <FlatList
   data={stData}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.registration_id}
   renderItem={({item}) => (
      <ListItem
         name={item.name}
         registrationNo={item.registration_id}
         data={stData}
         isPresent={item.isPresent}
         setData={setStData}
      />
   )}
```

/>

---

now `data={stData}`gonna evalute correctly, and `data.map` will be possible action

Comment: Actually, I am fetching stData from database (using useReducer) which is predefined accoridng to data coming from database. stData is an array of form **Array [ Object { "id": 1, "name":"Sameer" }, Object { "id": 2, "name":"Dev" } ]**

Comment: making my answer hopefully fit your needs

Comment: I added a new field in data named `isPresent`.
But I am getting **TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...props.data.map...')**

Comment: can you edit your question with current code, and expected behavior?

Comment: you sending like `isPresent={stData.item.isPresent}`, though is suppose to be `isPresent={stData.isPresent}` for the way you add it `{ ...item, isPresent: !props.isPresent }`. dont sure it that, post your outcome...

Comment: It is correct `isPresent={stData.item.isPresent}`. I am getting correct data in props.

Comment: Your edit is not working, child component is not receiving data after the edit. 
One mistake I found is that, it should be `props.data.item.map((value) =>)` because object are present in `props.data.item`
And when printing this  `props.data.item.registration_id === props.registrationNo` in log, it is printing true for every value.
 
But still getting the same error.

Comment: I have placed child component in the main component. The problem is that `stData.registration_id` is giving undefined because it can only be accessed using indexing `stData[i].registration_id`

Comment: my code actually can't work because `keyExtractor={(item)` and `renderItem={({item})` one destructed and one not. My best guess that this is the exact thing all the time, but in your code you use for the undestructerd the word `stData` what come over the data you wanted to sent

Comment: I solved it. You were right. Problem was in `renderItem={({item})`